# Detecting Targets using Python

Tags: image, computer-vision, target

I am new to python and I want to develop a code to detect the following targets.
[target to detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z44W.jpg)

[target to detect 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGCv5.jpg)

Any links would be appreciated..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN) to classify given image as one of the two. 
There are plenty of links for image classification using CNN in the Net.